# readOGR misses ExtendedData

Tags: r, kml, rgdal

Here's an excerpt of a KML I'm trying to read in with `readOGR`.  The `<ExtendedData>` content is being missed out:

**test.kml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Schema name="election-presidentielle-2017" id="election-presidentielle-2017">
      <SimpleField name="codreg" type="string">
        <displayName>Code Région</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="codreg3car" type="string">
        <displayName>Code Région 3</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="libreg" type="string">
        <displayName>Région</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="coddpt" type="string">
        <displayName>Code Département</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="codmindpt" type="string">
        <displayName>Code Département
        </displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="coddpt3car" type="string">
        <displayName>Code Département 3</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="libdpt" type="string">
        <displayName>Département</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="numtour" type="string">
        <displayName>Tour</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="codsubcom" type="string">
        <displayName>Code Commune</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="libsubcom" type="string">
        <displayName>Commune</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="nompsn" type="string">
        <displayName>Nom Candidat</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="prenompsn" type="string">
        <displayName>Prénom Candidat</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="civilitepsn" type="string">
        <displayName>Civilité Candidat</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="numpanneaucand" type="string">
        <displayName>Numéro Panneau Candidat</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="nbvoix" type="int">
        <displayName>Nombre de voix</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="rapportinscrit" type="double">
        <displayName>Rapport Inscrit</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="rapportexprime" type="double">
        <displayName>rapportexprime</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField name="code_insee" type="string">
        <displayName>Code Insee</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
    </Schema>
    <Placemark>
      <name>84</name>
      <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>4.9030768998,46.1579771394 4.903773126,46.157645709 4.9067820906,46.1562053906 4.9085001702,46.1548830643 4.9095492036,46.1537791314 4.9106569632,46.1525390878 4.9112674797,46.1517595766 4.9161461217,46.1453469021
              4.9160777584,46.1439086534 4.9156193663,46.1424337477 4.9145874913,46.1404541802 4.9093076435,46.1307852326 4.9093613658,46.1291638781 4.9158884782,46.127574897 4.9200298575,46.1257142424 4.9230135966,46.1235415672 4.9258961462,46.1201896347
              4.9262770895,46.120045356 4.9266095705,46.120218064 4.9315756331,46.1225684278 4.9367339062,46.1262421207 4.9378762749,46.127116182 4.9390381372,46.1283943404 4.9395243837,46.1291030402 4.9399472307,46.1298137221 4.940252746,46.1307966353
              4.9406425153,46.1321834498 4.9409012267,46.1335274654 4.9409959919,46.1341554766 4.940503709,46.134707048 4.9398299924,46.1395835589 4.9406706269,46.1415896 4.9428982044,46.1455436813 4.9460544153,46.1492521236 4.9463858083,46.1494238953
              4.9469685666,46.1494112058 4.948566391,46.1489685562 4.9578258548,46.1529852741 4.9582913471,46.1532447772 4.9553500484,46.1540331688 4.9508770382,46.1553071858 4.9453021789,46.1573520303 4.9431568487,46.1584102059 4.9401772735,46.1602923709
              4.9368787943,46.1618862443 4.9337395419,46.1626333003 4.931584178,46.1622772346 4.9312514883,46.1639105549 4.9316886461,46.1648390082 4.9330032704,46.167600886 4.9351734924,46.1696212725 4.9366153847,46.1699939409 4.9376185464,46.1706452011
              4.9387676797,46.1730044996 4.939996705,46.1756767881 4.9400915327,46.1763047983 4.9397434505,46.1771682606 4.9383177085,46.1785058892 4.9369448895,46.1796183085 4.9359306904,46.1800913711 4.9341221355,46.1815732794 4.9330127333,46.1827685385
              4.93289657,46.1830416412 4.9287600537,46.1832713453 4.916470741,46.1837323363 4.9147078505,46.183457594 4.9138535896,46.1832071613 4.913320385,46.1829035785 4.9095372185,46.1796146164 4.9088536889,46.1788649666 4.9074867671,46.176734229
              4.907292177,46.1690883427 4.905691265,46.1646916296 4.9045896831,46.1612287097 4.9045764202,46.1609587077 4.9042950093,46.1604698149 4.903096103,46.1583812534 4.9030768998,46.1579771394
            </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
      <ExtendedData>
        <SchemaData schemaUrl="election-presidentielle-2017">
          <SimpleData name="codreg">84</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="codreg3car">084</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="libreg">Auvergne et Rhône-Alpes</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="coddpt">01</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="codmindpt">01</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="coddpt3car">001</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="libdpt">Ain</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="numtour">1</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="codsubcom">001</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="libsubcom">L'Abergement-Clémenciat</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="nompsn">DUPONT-AIGNAN</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="prenompsn">Nicolas</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="civilitepsn">M.</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="numpanneaucand">1</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="nbvoix">34</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="rapportinscrit">5.69</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="rapportexprime">6.87</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="code_insee">01001</SimpleData>
        </SchemaData>
      </ExtendedData>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>84</name>
      <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>4.9030768998,46.1579771394 4.903773126,46.157645709 4.9067820906,46.1562053906 4.9085001702,46.1548830643 4.9095492036,46.1537791314 4.9106569632,46.1525390878 4.9112674797,46.1517595766 4.9161461217,46.1453469021
              4.9160777584,46.1439086534 4.9156193663,46.1424337477 4.9145874913,46.1404541802 4.9093076435,46.1307852326 4.9093613658,46.1291638781 4.9158884782,46.127574897 4.9200298575,46.1257142424 4.9230135966,46.1235415672 4.9258961462,46.1201896347
              4.9262770895,46.120045356 4.9266095705,46.120218064 4.9315756331,46.1225684278 4.9367339062,46.1262421207 4.9378762749,46.127116182 4.9390381372,46.1283943404 4.9395243837,46.1291030402 4.9399472307,46.1298137221 4.940252746,46.1307966353
              4.9406425153,46.1321834498 4.9409012267,46.1335274654 4.9409959919,46.1341554766 4.940503709,46.134707048 4.9398299924,46.1395835589 4.9406706269,46.1415896 4.9428982044,46.1455436813 4.9460544153,46.1492521236 4.9463858083,46.1494238953
              4.9469685666,46.1494112058 4.948566391,46.1489685562 4.9578258548,46.1529852741 4.9582913471,46.1532447772 4.9553500484,46.1540331688 4.9508770382,46.1553071858 4.9453021789,46.1573520303 4.9431568487,46.1584102059 4.9401772735,46.1602923709
              4.9368787943,46.1618862443 4.9337395419,46.1626333003 4.931584178,46.1622772346 4.9312514883,46.1639105549 4.9316886461,46.1648390082 4.9330032704,46.167600886 4.9351734924,46.1696212725 4.9366153847,46.1699939409 4.9376185464,46.1706452011
              4.9387676797,46.1730044996 4.939996705,46.1756767881 4.9400915327,46.1763047983 4.9397434505,46.1771682606 4.9383177085,46.1785058892 4.9369448895,46.1796183085 4.9359306904,46.1800913711 4.9341221355,46.1815732794 4.9330127333,46.1827685385
              4.93289657,46.1830416412 4.9287600537,46.1832713453 4.916470741,46.1837323363 4.9147078505,46.183457594 4.9138535896,46.1832071613 4.913320385,46.1829035785 4.9095372185,46.1796146164 4.9088536889,46.1788649666 4.9074867671,46.176734229
              4.907292177,46.1690883427 4.905691265,46.1646916296 4.9045896831,46.1612287097 4.9045764202,46.1609587077 4.9042950093,46.1604698149 4.903096103,46.1583812534 4.9030768998,46.1579771394
            </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
      <ExtendedData>
        <SchemaData schemaUrl="election-presidentielle-2017">
          <SimpleData name="codreg">84</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="codreg3car">084</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="libreg">Auvergne et Rhône-Alpes</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="coddpt">01</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="codmindpt">01</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="coddpt3car">001</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="libdpt">Ain</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="numtour">1</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="codsubcom">001</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="libsubcom">L'Abergement-Clémenciat</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="nompsn">LE PEN</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="prenompsn">Marine</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="civilitepsn">Mme</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="numpanneaucand">2</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="nbvoix">126</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="rapportinscrit">21.07</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="rapportexprime">25.45</SimpleData>
          <SimpleData name="code_insee">01001</SimpleData>
        </SchemaData>
      </ExtendedData>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

And..

```
require(rgdal)
x = readOGR('test.kml', layer=ogrListLayers("test.kml"), verbose=T)
#> OGR data source with driver: KML 
#> Source: "test.kml", layer: "Layer #0"
#> with 2 features
#> It has 2 fields
x@data
#>   Name Description
#> 0   84            
#> 1   84
```

[Not a new problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785463/readogr-rgdal-fails-to-fetch-polygon-names-from-xml) but I can't find a soluition. Any suggestions? If `readOGR` can't manage it I wonder if there's a method to reformat `<ExtendedData>` (maybe outside R) into readable tags?

Answer (score 0):

OK this `node.js` workflow extracts the `<ExtendedData>` content to csv (along with the rest):

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV test.csv test.kml
```

..and you can reunite with spatial data in R, e.g.

```
spdf@data = read.csv('test.csv')
```